# Deriving a text string from a date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I could use some help deriving a year quarter from a text string that represents a date. I have a string, say '20121230', to represent 12/30/2012. Somehow, someway, I need to convert this value into '4Q12.' I get stuck after converting the 20121230 into a date:

```
CONVERT(date,datestringfield,111)
```

I need help deriving the quarter and year from this date and then converting the quarter and year to a string format 4Q12. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you using SQL Server?, wich version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then the particular format of `datestringfield` can be used as a date unambiguosly. So, you can do:

```
SELECT  DATENAME(QUARTER,datestringfield) + 'Q' + 
        RIGHT('00'+DATENAME(YEAR,datestringfield),2)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I received an error reading "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type datetime."

Comment: @Deep Then you have impossible dates. As you post in your question, your values should have the format `YYYYMMDD`, but if you get that error, you may have values like `YYYDDMM` (`'20122501'`) or just values with wrong dates like `'20120230'`